# SAS Return header conditionally

Tags: loops, header, sas

I have data set that looks like this :

[Data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFq03.jpg)

And would like get the result that will look like this:
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FicbD.jpg)

Thanks for your help

Comment: You should put the sample HAVE and WANT in your question as text, not links to images. Actually for HAVE , even better is DATA step code to make the HAVE data set.  Also describe the logic you are trying to implement, and include the code you have tried.

Comment: I thought I already attached the 'Have' and "Want' option .. Please click the attached link " Data set"  for data I have now - And 'desired result" for the want data.

Comment: Basically I want go through the data and output the fist empty rows per header name ( Flag) ..please see  the "desired result"

Comment: Posting HAVE as text makes it easier for others to help you. Otherwise every person who wants to help you has to start by typing it in for themselves.

Comment: It looks like you have posted small photographs of some cells in a spreadsheet.  Can you just copy the cells as text and paste them into the question so that others can use the sample data?  It probably would have been much easier to start that way than go to the effort of taking the photographs to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

**Way1:** Using `proc sql`

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select name,group1,group2,group3,
case when group1 is null then 'group1'
     when group2 is null then 'group2'
     when group3 is null then 'group3'
end as flag
from have;
quit;
```

**Way2:** Using `datastep`

```
data want;
set have;
if      group1 is null then flag = 'group1';
else if group2 is null then flag = 'group2';
else if group3 is null then flag = 'group3';
else flag = 'check';
run;
```

Let me know in case of any clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to avoid hard coding you can use array.

> ```
> data have;
>   infile datalines dlm=',' dsd;
>   input name $ grp1 grp2 grp3;
>   datalines;
>     Joe,,1, 
>     Moe,1,1, 
>     King,1,,1
>     Penn,,,1
>     Zhee,1,,, 
>   ;
> run;
>
> data want;
>   set have;
>   length flag $10;
>   call missing(flag);
>
>   array chars(3) grp1 grp2 grp3;
>     do i=1 to 3;
>       if chars(i)=. & flag='' then flag=catx(' ',"Group",i);
>     end;
>   drop i;
> run;
> ```

You could also use `VNAME(chars(i))` function call to replace the `CATX function`  call in the code in which case you would change grp to group in the variable names.

Answer (score 0):

To find the name of a variable you can use the `VNAME()` function.  You can use an array to search over all of the individual input flag variables and when you find a missing one use VNAME() to get its name.

```
data have;
  input name $ group1-group3 ;
cards;
Joe  . 1 .
Moe  1 1 . 
King 1 . 1
Penn . . 1
Zhee 1 . .
None 1 1 1
;

data want ;
  set have ;
  array flags group1-group3 ;
  length flag $32 ;
  do _n_=1 to dim(flags) while (missing(flag));
    if missing(flags(_n_)) then flag=vname(flags(_n_));
  end;
run;
proc print;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    name    group1    group2    group3     flag
 1     Joe        .         1         .      group1
 2     Moe        1         1         .      group3
 3     King       1         .         1      group2
 4     Penn       .         .         1      group1
 5     Zhee       1         .         .      group2
 6     None       1         1         1
```